# Change Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS Bionic Console Screen Resolution

Tags: server, grub2, 18.04, virtualbox, console

- Running Ubuntu 18.04 sever on a physical machine or VirtualBox?
- Do you need/want to use the full native resolution of your screen? Higher than 640x480 / 800x600?

Then you may be stuck as I've been, because the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662744/change-ubuntu-server-14-04-screen-resolution) that used to work on 14.04 and 16.04 doesn't work on 18.04.

**Problems to solve** (goals)

1. `hwinfo --framebuffer` gives an empty output -> find another solution
2. adding the usual lines to /etc/default/grub, only helps at the first stage of the boot. After GRUB2 has done its work, the resolution switches back to a lower value -> resolve this too
3. exclude xorg based tools like xrandr (this is a server without GUI by default)
4. increase VT1-7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> - <kbd>F7</kbd> ) resolution in case of Desktop systems with a GUI
5. set the resolution to 1280x1024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Get supported video mode** (use `vbeinfo` instead of hwinfo)

- reboot
- hold down SHIFT after the BIOS/UEFI finished
- press `c´ for the GRUB command line
- type `set pager=1`, then hit ENTER
- type `vbeinfo`, then hit ENTER
- take a note about the supported video mode you need `Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+3840), 24 bits`
- reboot

**2. Modify / add the following lines** to `/etc/default/grub` to match the ones below

```
>     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=0x0345 gfxpayload=true"
>     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=0x0345 gfxpayload=true"
>     ...
>     # The resolution used on graphical terminal
>     # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
>     # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
>     GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024x24
>     GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1280x1024x24
>     GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024x24
```

**3. Update GRUB**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**4. Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

---

**Note1:** I've tested the above solution with Ubuntu 18.04 Server and Desktop on VirtualBox.

**Note2:** Didn't include linux terminal (emulator), putty, cygwin, conemu and other fancy tools, because this is about the bare console.

---

None of the sources I used had a complete solution, but putting the parts together, solved the problem for me.

[Change Ubuntu Server 14.04 Screen Resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662744/change-ubuntu-server-14-04-screen-resolution)

https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1468789.html

Comment: "error: can't find command `vbeinfo`."

Comment: @IRGeekSauce please go to step one and follow carefully. What is your operating system version?

Answer (score 0):

But sometimes you need the monitor natives text resolution so it scroll faster.

**1. Get supported video mode** (use `vbeinfo` instead of hwinfo)

- reboot
- hold down SHIFT after the BIOS/UEFI finished
- press `c´ for the GRUB command line
- type `set pager=1`, then hit ENTER
- type `vbeinfo`, then hit ENTER
- take a note about the supported video mode you need `Mode 0x100: 640 x 400 x 8 (640) Paletted`
- reboot

**2. Modify / add the following lines** to `/etc/default/grub` to match the ones below

```
>     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
>     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
>     ...
>     # The resolution used on graphical terminal
>     # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
>     # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
>     GRUB_GFXMODE=640x400x8
>     GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

**3. Update GRUB**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**4. Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with this issue on DELL XPS13 ubuntu edition, I found out another way to make it work properly by changing the cmdline:

from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=eDP-1:1920x1080"
```

you might need to change the value of *eDP-1* as it's referring to the connector you want to modify. The active connector can be found in */sys/class/drm/CONNECTOR/status*